# Two unicode encodings represent 1 cyrillic letter

Tags: python, java, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have such string in unicode and utf-8 representation:

```
\u00d0\u0095\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082 \u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083
```

and

```
Ð•ÑÐ»Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾Ð²ÐµÐ·ÐµÑ‚ Ñ‚Ð¾ ÑÐµÐ³Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñ ÑƒÐ¶Ðµ ÑÐºÐ¸Ð½Ñƒ.
```

The desired ouput is "Если повезет то сегодня уже скину".

I have tried all possible encodings but still wasn't able to get it in complete cyrillic form.

The best I got was

```
'�?�?ли повезе�? �?о �?егодн�? �?же �?кин�?'
```

using windows-1252.

And also I've noticed that one cyrillic letter in desired string means two unicode encodings.

For example: `\u00d0\u0095 = 'Е'`.
Maybe someone knows what encoding and how to use it to get a normal result?

Comment: I've tried utf-8, 16, and 32 on both strings (`ÐÑÐ»Ð` and `Если`) but none of them encode to that byte representation. Do you know what encoding this is supposed to be? And how does `\u00d0 \u0095` become one character? Both of them are ascii characters. `d0` prints something on its own and `95` doesn't (although it should be a backwards-pointing-accented o). Did you mean to use the capital unicode for the longer ones: `\U00d00095`?

Comment: `new String("\u00d0\u0095\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082 \u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083".getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: About the title of your question: *all* Cyrillic characters occupy 2 bytes in UTF-8.  So, not 2 Unicode encodings: *one* encoding that is a sequence of 2 bytes. This is normal and unsurprising. There are (obviously) only 256 one-byte UTF-8 encodings, of which the first 127 are mirrors of ascii. Scripts other than latin wouldn't fit in what remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mis-decoded string where the UTF-8 bytes were translated as ISO-8859-1 (also known as `latin1`).  Ideally, re-download with the correct encoding, but you can also encode with the wrongly-used encoding to regain the original byte stream, then decode with the right encoding (UTF-8):

Python:

```py
>>> s = '\u00d0\u0095\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082 \u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083'
>>> s
'Ð\x95Ñ\x81Ð»Ð¸Ð¿Ð¾Ð²ÐµÐ·ÐµÑ\x82 Ñ\x82Ð¾Ñ\x81ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñ\x8fÑ\x83Ð¶ÐµÑ\x81ÐºÐ¸Ð½Ñ\x83'
>>> print(s)
ÐÑÐ»Ð¸Ð¿Ð¾Ð²ÐµÐ·ÐµÑ ÑÐ¾ÑÐµÐ³Ð¾Ð´Ð½ÑÑÐ¶ÐµÑÐºÐ¸Ð½Ñ
>>> s.encode('latin1')
b'\xd0\x95\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8f\xd1\x83\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x83'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'Еслиповезет тосегодняужескину'
```

You may also have a literal string of Unicode escape codes, which is a bit trickier:

```
>>> s=r'\u00d0\u0095\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082 \u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083'
>>> print(s)
\u00d0\u0095\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082 \u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083
```

In this case, the string has to be converted back to bytes, decoded as Unicode escapes, then encoded back to bytes and correctly decoded as UTF-8.  `latin1` has the feature that the first 256 code points of Unicode map to bytes 0-255 in that codec, so it converts 1:1 code point to byte value.

```py
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'Еслиповезет тосегодняужескину'
```

Answer (score 3):

`d0 95 d1 81 d0 bb d0 b8` is the correct UTF-8 octet stream for `"Если"`.

So you need to convert each character to a byte (8-bit word, octet) by removing the most significant part (which is always 0 anyway in your example). Then decode them as UTF-8.

Or better, go back to the source from which you got this, and make sure the stream of octets is not seen as single-byte encoding.